# Über die Wendung "Auf Augenhöhe mit jm/etw."

Tags: phrase

> Etymologisch bedeutete das Wort "Geiz" ursprünglich einmal verlangen
>   oder begehren. Übertriebener Ehrgeiz **steht** daher mit der "Gier"
>   **auf Augenhöhe**.

und

> Aber **ist** dieser Roboter momentan **auf Augenhöhe mit** dem Menschen?

Handelt es sich hier um zwei verschiedene Wendungen oder ist das die gleiche Wendung, die aber zu vielen Verben passt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Wendung passt zu vielen Verben, so auch zu **verhandeln**, **spielen** (Fußball u.ä.), **konkurrieren** um etw. oder jemanden usw.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist die gleiche Wendung; sie kann in beiden Fällen durch *ist gleichwertig mit* ersetzt werden.

Die aktuelle Beliebtheit der Phrase kann ich mir nicht erklären. Von physikalischer Größe auf andere Eigenschaften wie Ausdrucksfähigkeit Durchsetzungsvermögen oder Vielseitigkeit zu schließen, finde ich eher bemüht.

Comment: So ist das eben mit Redewendungen. "Ist gleichwertig mit" bedeutet ja auch, dass es den gleichen Wert aufweist. Dabei kann man ja Dinge wie Ausdrucksfähigkeit auch nicht mit einem Wert einstufen.